# Difference between two DateTimes C#?

Tags: c#, date, datediff

I need a function that can return the difference between the below two dates as 24.

```
DateTime a = new DateTime(2008, 01, 02, 06, 30, 00);
DateTime b = new DateTime(2008, 01, 03, 06, 30, 00);
```

Answer (score 221, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
TimeSpan duration = b - a;
```

There's plenty of built in methods in the timespan class to do what you need, i.e.

```
duration.TotalSeconds
duration.TotalMinutes
```

More info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).

Comment: TimeSpan span = x.ShiftEndTime.Subtract(x.ShiftStartTime)
if (span.TotalHours == 24) {do...}

Answer (score 24):

Try the following

```
double hours = (b-a).TotalHours;
```

If you just want the hour difference excluding the difference in days you can use the following

```
int hours = (b-a).Hours;
```

The difference between these two properties is mainly seen when the time difference is more than 1 day.  The Hours property will only report the actual hour difference between the two dates.  So if two dates differed by 100 years but occurred at the same time in the day, hours would return 0.  But TotalHours will return the difference between in the total amount of hours that occurred between the two dates (876,000 hours in this case).

The other difference is that TotalHours will return fractional hours.  This may or may not be what you want.  If not, Math.Round can adjust it to your liking.

Comment: Still wrong. TotalHours is a double, returning whole and fractional hours.

Comment: Its the right answer for the question, he wants the result to be 24 which it would be. Of course he could round the TotalHours himself quite easily if that is what he wants.

Comment: @James my answer produces 24 exactly.  The OP did not specify the value had to be a particular number format.

Comment: @abmv: "OP" - Original Poster. In this case, you.

Comment: @Jared, I know I was agreeing with you. I think your answer is the better answer than the chosen one.

Comment: @James, sorry.  Only halfway throught the first cup of coffee this morning and not completely awake.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you perhaps looking for:

```
int Difference = (a-b).Hours;
```

Comment: Would actually need to be 


int Difference = (a-b).TotalHours;

Answer (score 1):

```
int hours = (int)Math.Round((b - a).TotalHours)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var theDiff24 = (b-a).Hours
```

Answer (score 0):

The time difference b/w to time will be shown use this method.

```
 private void HoursCalculator()
    {
        var t1 = txtfromtime.Text.Trim();
        var t2 = txttotime.Text.Trim();
        var Fromtime = t1.Substring(6);
        var Totime = t2.Substring(6);
        if (Fromtime == "M")
        {
             Fromtime = t1.Substring(5);
        }
        if (Totime == "M")
        {
            Totime = t2.Substring(5);
        }

        if (Fromtime=="PM" && Totime=="AM" )
        {
            var dt1 = DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 " + txtfromtime.Text.Trim());
            var dt2 = DateTime.Parse("1900-01-02 " + txttotime.Text.Trim());
            var t = dt1.Subtract(dt2);
            //int temp = Convert.ToInt32(t.Hours);
            //temp = temp / 2;
            lblHours.Text =t.Hours.ToString() + ":" + t.Minutes.ToString();

        }
        else if (Fromtime == "AM" && Totime == "PM")
        {
            var dt1 = DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 " + txtfromtime.Text.Trim());
            var dt2 = DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 " + txttotime.Text.Trim());
            TimeSpan t = (dt2.Subtract(dt1));
            lblHours.Text = t.Hours.ToString() + ":" + t.Minutes.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            var dt1 = DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 " + txtfromtime.Text.Trim());
            var dt2 = DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 " + txttotime.Text.Trim());
            TimeSpan t = (dt2.Subtract(dt1));
            lblHours.Text = t.Hours.ToString() + ":" + t.Minutes.ToString();
        }
    }
```

use your field id's

**var t1** captures a value of **4:00AM**

check this code may be helpful to someone.